# AdalSilentTokenAcquisitionException when trying to acquire the token in c#

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to connect to my azure application using the `acquireTokenSilentAsync` but i'm getting an exception, this is the code:

```
public class Oauth
    {
        public const string OAuthHeader = "Authorization";
        public static  String GetUserAccessTokenAsync()
        {
            AuthenticationResult result = null;
            string aadTenant = TestConfiguration.Default.ActiveDirectoryTenant;
            string aadClientAppId = TestConfiguration.Default.ActiveDirectoryClientAppId;
            string aadResource = TestConfiguration.Default.ActiveDirectoryResource;

            var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(aadTenant, TokenCache.DefaultShared);

            result = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(aadResource, aadClientAppId).Result;

            if (result != null)
            {
                var accessToken = result.AccessToken;
                // Use the token
                return accessToken;
            }
            else
            {
                return "";
            }
        }
    }
```

**I'm getting this error below on this line:**

```
result = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(aadResource, aadClientAppId).Result;
```

> AdalSilentTokenAcquisitionException: Failed to acquire token silently as no token was found in the cache. Call method AcquireToken

what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to get the token silently, it will get the token from the TokenCache or silently use refreshToken. So when there are no tokens in the cache, the AdalException returns. You could refer to this [article](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/AcquireTokenSilentAsync-using-a-cached-token).

> **Note that**, `AcquireTokenSilent` does not need to be called in the Client
> credentials flow (when the application acquires token without a user,
> but in its own name)
>
> **Note that** `AcquireTokenSilent` can fail for several reasons, such as the
> cache does not contain a token for the user, or the token has expired
> and cannot be refreshed.

```
try
{
    result = await ac.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(resource, clientId);
}
catch (AdalException adalException)
{
    if (adalException.ErrorCode == AdalError.FailedToAcquireTokenSilently
        || adalException.ErrorCode == AdalError.InteractionRequired)
    {
        result = await ac.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientId, redirectUri,
                                       new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto));
    }
}
```